# Several Regressions_Modify the code

Tags: r

When I run the code below, I can calculate the regression's coefficients for each category of c. Now I was wondering how I can apply these estimated coefficients to calculate the residuals of all observations. For example, here just 25 observations belong to c=1, but I need to calculate the fitted values/Residuals of all 50 observations based on the estimated coefficients for this category.

```
A<-cars$speed
B<-cars$dist
c<-rep(1:2,25)
S<-data.frame(A,B,c)
library(plyr) 
lmodel <- dlply(S,"c", function(d) lm(B~A, data = d))
```

Comment: `predict(..., newdata=S)`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you mean, but the following code will give you a list of residuals. The first element of the list contains the residuals for all 50 observations using the coefficients for `c=1` and the second for `c=2`.

```
residuals<- lapply(lmodel, function(x) B - coef(x)[1] - coef(x)[2]*A)
```

Comment: thanks so much for the comment, but I didn't understand how you calculated the residuals.
based on the first component the coefficients are Intercept=-18.618 and slope=4.094. So the formula for calculating
the residuals would be Y-yhat=Y-(-18.618+4.094X). Am I right?

Comment: @david I forgot the intercept, sorry! I edited the code above to work.